# Разница в переменных в Java и Python

Tags: java, python

товарищи. Я долгое время программировал на Java, сейчас затронул Python и в голове немного помешалось. Помогите выпутаться) Прав ли я в следующем? В Java у нас есть примитивные и ссылочные переменные. Разница в том, что примитивные переменные ссылаются на непосредственно значение, а ссылочная - на ссылку, ведущую в более глубокую область памяти. А в Python у нас все переменные аналогичны ссылочным в Java.

Comment: именно, это свойство кстати путает большинство новичков, когда обе переменные ссылаются на 1 объект, и при изменении одного меняется другой

Comment: Всё верно. Можете посмотреть видео в блоке 1.2 этого курса https://stepik.org/lesson/24458/step/1?unit=6765 там всё это объясняется, хоть и довольно простым языком

Answer (score 5):

В Java есть примитивные типы и есть объекты. Переменные примитивных типов содержат значение, а переменные типа `class` содержат ссылки на объекты.

В Python идея ООП доведена до абсолюта и:

> Everything Is an Object

то есть всё является объектами, то есть с точки зрения Java программиста - все переменные  в Python являются ссылками на объекты.

Answer (score 2):

Вы правы.

Наиболее важные отличия Python от Java:

**1) Все переменные - это просто указатели.**

Пример:

```py
>>> x = [1, 2]
>>> y = x # переменная y ссылается на тот же список, что и x
>>> print(y)
>>> y.append(3) # добавим элемент к y
>>> print(x) # x тоже изменился
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x = 4 # присвоим x какое-то иное значение
>>> print(y) # y не поменялся
[1, 2, 3]
```

**2) Все переменные - это объекты.**

```py
>>> x = 3.0
>>> x.is_integer() # вызовем метод
True
>>> type(x) # проверим тип переменной
<type 'float'>
>>> x.__class__ # тип - это просто название класса
<type 'float'>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Коротко говоря все переменные в python это ссылки на какие то объекты, даже переменные примитивных типов. Подтверждение этому можно увидеть например так:

```py
>>> a = 5
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
```

Но при этом любой объект типа `int` является неизменяемым (immutable). Пусть мы написали `a = 5`. Мы никаким образом не можем изменить содержимое области памяти на которую ссылается `a`, можем только начать ссылаться на другую область, например написав `a = 6`. Если проводить аналогии с Java то в python доступен только класс `Integer` но не примитивный тип `int` из Java

## Бонус

Интересный факт: для типа `int` числа до 256 кешируются, то есть `a = 5` и `b = 5` это один и тот же объект (`a` и `b` ссылаются на одну область памяти), но при этом `a = 257` и `b = 257` это уже два разных объекта (`a` и `b` ссылаются разные области памяти)

```py
>>> a = 256
>>> b = 256
>>> id(a)
10922656
>>> id(b)
10922656
>>> a = 257
>>> b = 257
>>> id(a)
139993530665008
>>> id(b)
139993530663408
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!